# Plot multiple boxplots from seaborn with hue

Tags: pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataframe with three columns

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data = {'Dose1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Dose2': [6,6,4,7,4],'SickOrNot':[True,False,True,True,False]})
```

The last column corresponds to whether or not a patient stayed sick and the first two columns are doses of two drugs administered to the patient. I want to create two pairs of boxplots (in seaborn) of the doses, using whether the patient was sick or not as a hue.

So, essentially, I want the x axis to have two sections (Dose 1, Dose 2), which each section containing two boxplots. So that my final four boxplots are that of Dose 1 of sick patients, dose 1 of non sick patients, dose 2 of sick patients, dose 2 of non sick patients.

What is the syntax that I would use to do this? I have tried setting hue to be 'sick or not' but I am very confused about what to set as my x and y values when calling `sns.boxplot`.

Answer (score 3):

Reshape the data into [long form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) such that each column is one variable and each row is one observation. In this case `Dose1` and `Dose2` should be combined into one column, e.g. `Section`.

[`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the data with `SickOrNot` as the identifier and `Dose1` and `Dose2` as the values. Then set `SickOrNot` as the plot's `hue`:

```py
sns.boxplot(
    data=df.melt(id_vars=['SickOrNot'], value_vars=['Dose1', 'Dose2'],
                 var_name='Section', value_name='Dosage'),
    x='Section',
    y='Dosage',
    hue='SickOrNot',
)
```

[image: box plot after melting]